# Store JSON into array

Tags: json, swift

I need to store each part of the json into a data structure, maybe Array?

This is what I have when I call Firebase realtime:

```
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let key = snap.key
        let value = snap.value

        print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n\n")

        print("key = \(key)  value = \(value!)")
    }
})
```

when printed it looks like this:

[image]

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I need to store the title, description and postUrl

**EDIT:**

If I do this:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("post").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  print(snapshot)
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

that would give me the snapshot id but not the values because the user is not in that DB, how can I print the snapshots without saying current user?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just ask for the snapshot's `value`. If this is an array, that's the array right there.

Comment: If you can't take @matt's approach, which seems the obvious way, then you're going to have to treat the value as a string and process it manually 9as it's not valid JSON).

Comment: @matt How would I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't for some reason access the snapshot's value parameter as above, you will probably need to manually parse the `value` string (as it's not proper json).  The code below will allow you to initialise the data structure with the `value` text.  This assumes `value` is a nicely formed string as in the example below.  If not you may need to play with it a bit more:

```
let valueString = """
{
description = dawdled
postUrl = http://darrengillman.com
timestamp = 1572735278831
title = testy
}
"""

struct DataStruct {
   let decription: String
   let postUrl: URL
   let timestamp: Int
   let test: String

   init?(from value: String) {
      let strings = Array(value.components(separatedBy: .newlines).dropLast().dropFirst()).map{$0.components(separatedBy: "=")}.map{$0.dropFirst().first!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}
      guard strings.count == 4 else {return nil}
      self.decription = strings[0]
      self.postUrl = URL(string: strings[1])!
      self.timestamp = Int(strings[2]) ?? 0
      self.test = strings[3]
   }
}

let myData = DataStruct(from: valueString)
```

Comment: How does that integrates on my code? I'm new to swift and firebase. Do I include that in the `for child in snapshot.children {` loop?

Comment: It's just a possible way to load the data from the key-value pair.  Where you load it will depend on your architecture, but that loop sounds like a good place.  However the approach from @Matt in the comments should be the first thing you try,  Use the native API wherever possible.

Comment: How can I do the approach that Matt said?

Comment: The things is that if I try to ask for the snapshot value using the current user, I get null, cause the user is stored somewhere else